# SQL all data from table one some data from table 2

Tags: sql

Probably a dumb question: buts I've spent enough hours that I really need some outside help.

I have one table that has a list of names: some of thse sames may not be in table two and I need all names listed.

In a second table I have the some of same names, but these names can be listed with an event date and an event type.

How would I list all the names from table one.
And also include the events from table two given specific event types.

This means that is a name in table one is not linked to an event in table two it will still print.

I have tried left outer join: but cannot still figure out how to limit the data coming from table two: or if I place a where clause the where clause seems to nullify adding all names from table 1 because they do not meet the parameters I place on table 2.

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: shows what you tried to do so we can try to correct it or improve it  and show also a proper data sample and expected result

Comment: When using an `outer join` with `where` criteria, you need to move the `where` criteria to the `on` criteria of the `join` so it doesn't negate the `outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server my suggestion is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblNames(
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO tblNames (Name) VALUES ('Jim'), ('Jack'), ('Joe')
GO

CREATE TABLE tblEvents(
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    EventDate NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,
    EventType NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO tblEvents (Name, EventDate, EventType) VALUES
    ('Jim', '04/05/2000', 'Birthday'),
    ('Joe', '01/01/1999', 'Marriage')
GO

SELECT 
    tblNames.Name,
    tblEvents.EventDate,
    tblEvents.EventType 
FROM tblNames
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEvents
        ON tblNames.Name = tblEvents.Name 
            AND tblEvents.EventType = 'Birthday'
```

It will give you all the Names in column Names and if there is a entry in tblEvents with the matching event type you'll have that info in the other columns.

Comment: couldn't one also forgo the nested query and instead place a second criteria on the join like `on tblNames.Name = tblEvents.Name and tblEvents.EventType = 'Birthday'`

Comment: @Todd you are completely right. That's much nicer and more compact. I edited the sample. Thx.